# Integrating a second derivative

Tags: integration, derivatives, substitution

Admit that $f$ has a second derivative find the integer $m$.

$$m\int_{0}^{1}xf''(2x)dx = \int_0^2xf''(x)dx$$

So I took $2x=u$ where $du/dx=2$ and I plugged in the integral getting

$$\frac{m}{4}\int_{0}^{2}uf''(u)du =\frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{2} uf''(\frac{u}{2})du$$

How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Let $2x=t$.Then ${\rm d}x=\dfrac{1}{2}{\rm d}t$, and $t=0,2$ as $x=0,1$, respectively. Thus
$$m\int_{0}^{1}xf''(2x)dx =m\int_{0}^{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}t\right)f''(t)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right){\rm d}t=\frac{m}{4}\int_{0}^{2}tf''(t){\rm d}t ,$$

namely, $$\frac{m}{4}\int_{0}^{2}xf''(x){\rm d}x.$$

Thus,$$\frac{m}{4}\int_{0}^{2}xf''(x){\rm d}x=\int_{0}^{2}xf''(x){\rm d}x.$$
As a result,$$\frac{m}{4}=1,$$i.e. $$m=4.$$

Answer (score 0):

So as you observed, substituting $2x \to x$ in the LHS we have

$$m\int_0^1 x f''(2x) \, \mathrm d x = \frac m 4 \int_0^2 x f''(x) \, \mathrm d x$$

Thus $m=4$.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea where your second integral comes from. Your first integral in the second equality is equal to $m\int_0^1 xf''(2x)\,dx$. For this to be $\int_0^2 x f''(x)dx$, you need $m/4=1$, i.e. $m=4$.

Comment: Oh I see, I don't know how I missed that, I was making things way more complicated, thanks.

Comment: Don't worry, we all do.